Flask session value not persisting between routes
I am working on a Flask application where I need to retrieve a value set in one route inside another route. I am trying to set a value in the session inside the payment_callback function and retrieve it in the payment_result function. However, the value is None when I try to access it in payment_result.
Here is my code:
@app.route('/payment/callback', methods=['POST'])
def payment_callback():
    global processed_transactions

try:
    data = get_request_data()
    logger.info(f"Received data: {data}")
    response_status = decode_if_bytes(data.get('payment_result', {}).get('response_status'))
    if response_status:
        session['response_status'] = response_status
        logger.info(f"Callback session data: {dict(session)}")
    else:
        logger.warning("Response status not found in the received data.")
    return redirect(url_for('payment_result'))

except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error querying transaction: {e}")
    flash('Error querying transaction', 'danger')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
 
@app.route('/payment/return', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def payment_return():
    time.sleep(3)
    logger.info('------return--------')
    return redirect(url_for('payment_result'))

@app.route('/payment/result')
def payment_result():
    print('I want to get response status')
    response_status = session.get('response_status')
    print(response_status)  # Output is NONE----------------- here is the problem
    return render_template('Payment_Result.html')

Log output:
INFO:main:Received data: {'tran_ref': 'TST2417201883637', 'merchant_id': 78035, 'profile_id': 137790, 'cart_id': 'card_123', 'cart_description': 'Sample Payment', 'cart_currency': 'EGP', 'cart_amount': '10.00', 'tran_currency': 'EGP', 'tran_total': '10.00', 'tran_type': 'Sale', 'tran_class': 'ECom', 'customer_details': {'name': 'shady Henawy wardy', 'email': 'shadywardy@gmail.com', 'street1': 'Cairo', 'city': 'Cairo', 'state': 'GZ', 'country': 'EG', 'zip': '11637', 'ip': '197.49.115.176'}, 'payment_result': {'response_status': 'A', 'response_code': 'G01271', 'response_message': 'Authorised', 'acquirer_ref': 'TRAN0001.66745A17.0003D57B', 'cvv_result': ' ', 'avs_result': ' ', 'transaction_time': '2024-06-20T16:34:31Z'}, 'payment_info': {'payment_method': 'Visa', 'card_type': 'Credit', 'card_scheme': 'Visa', 'payment_description': '4000 00## #### 0002', 'expiryMonth': 6, 'expiryYear': 2029}, 'ipn_trace': 'IPNS0001.66745A17.00005B19'}

INFO:main:Callback session data: {'response_status': 'A'}

INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024 19:34:38] "POST /payment/callback HTTP/1.1" 302 -

INFO:main:------return--------

INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024 19:34:41] "GET /payment/return HTTP/1.1" 302 -

INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2024 19:34:41] "GET /payment/result HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I want to get response status

None

Expected Behavior: The session['response_status'] set in payment_callback should be accessible in payment_result.
Actual Behavior: The value of session['response_status'] is None in payment_result.
Additional Information: I have verified that the session is being set correctly in payment_callback, as shown in the logs.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

What exactly is session (incl. configuration)? And as a side not: global is a no-go in web applications: a WSGI server might split requests between different workers and eventually recycle them. This will lead to multiple and purged versions of the value.

sorry iam just junior in web app ,, i donot unerstand what do you mean
